# Python - Is there a way to alter a specific line inside a file?

Tags: python, file

I'm creating an API for remote Snort rule configuration. I'm working mainly with three actions regarding the rules: "Create", "Delete" and "Halt". The problem i'm having is with the Delete and Halt actions, the rules in snort are saved in a file where each line corresponds to a rule, so to Delete a rule i would need to iterate through the file, find the specific rule and somehow delete that line from the file. Similar thing with Halt, find the line and insert an # at the beginning.

I've created this function to iterate through the file, find the rule i want and return in which line it's located:

```
def findRule(fileName, ruleString):
    with open(fileName,"r+") as file:
        lineCounter = 1
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            if line == ruleString:
                return lineCounter
            lineCounter += 1
```

With the above function i can get the line of a given rule inside a file, my problem (again) is: how to manipulate (insert # at the beginning, completely remove) that specific line ? Is python the best language to do that?

Any module/language recomendation is welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Python got nothing with that and in you simply need to rewrite the file if you need to change anything in it (with the exception of appending data to the file, which is not the case here).